# Creating temp directory in www for download CentOS

Tags: linux, unix

I need to create temp directory in a specific location under `var/www/html` so anybody can download it for a several mins.

How can i do that?

`mktemp -d` generates under `/tmp/xxxxx`

Comment: You can pass a path to [`mktemp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) in the template, or use `--tmpdir`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

try this; mktemp -d /var/www/html/a.XXXX